# Upgrading PCF platform with high availability?

Tags: cloud-foundry

New to PCF and trying to get a better understanding of the platform best practices.

My question is how do you upgrade the PCF platform without downtime? For example if I wanted to upgrade from PCF 1.10 to PCF 1.11.

Comment: Upgrading PCF to the next version is not as easy as upgrading to next version of ERT. There are lot more considerations that goes in, before you upgrade. My suggestion, you reach out to Pivotal and have Pivotal engineers along the journey.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the links on upgrading PCF

To ver 1.11 - https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/1-11/customizing/upgrading-pcf.html

To ver 1.12 - https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/1-12/customizing/upgrading-pcf.html